# How to get finished content of a webpage using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to get the content of [https://apps.shopify.com/](https://apps.shopify.com/search?q=a) as a html response to save it in a file for further processing (I need the list of names and URls for those apps for a scraping task).

I tried to use httpget, axios and request but all returns an unrendered version (I think page uses JS to add the products later). I need finished html code. How can I get the finished result in NodeJS?

(Or if anyone knows an API to search shopify appstore).

Comment: You misunderstand how the web works...

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood my question . puppeteer can render websites easily and even take screenshots. I just need the html of that.

Comment: Try Puppeteer's `await page.content()` to get the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### To iterate over all app links, retrieve url and text:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    var url = 'https://apps.shopify.com/search?q=a';

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

    await page.waitForXPath('//a[@data-app-link-details]');
    const links = await page.$x('//a[@data-app-link-details]');
    for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        let hrefp = await links[i].getProperty('href');
        let href = await hrefp.jsonValue();
        let txt = await links[i].getProperty('textContent');
        let text = await txt.jsonValue();
        console.log(href + " " + text);
    }

    await browser.close();
})();
```

### Output

```
https://apps.shopify.com/automizely-loyalty?locale=fr&search_id=22d826ac-82ca-42ef-ad32-d2736ba59bc8&surface_detail=a&surface_inter_position=1&surface_intra_position=22&surface_type=search 
            Automizely Referral&Affiliate
          
https://apps.shopify.com/klaviyo-email-marketing?locale=fr&search_id=22d826ac-82ca-42ef-ad32-d2736ba59bc8&surface_detail=a&surface_inter_position=1&surface_intra_position=23&surface_type=search 
            Klaviyo: Email Marketing & SMS
          
https://apps.shopify.com/govx-id?locale=fr&search_id=22d826ac-82ca-42ef-ad32-d2736ba59bc8&surface_detail=a&surface_inter_position=1&surface_intra_position=24&surface_type=search 
            GovX ID Exclusive Discounts
[...]
```

Comment: Is there a class selector in puppeteer? you have used '//a[@data-app-link-details]' for selecting the href. This class tag has multiple classes and its the only one in the page with all those.

Comment: Oh I found it.. I used @class="" without all classes. Now it's working fine.

Comment: Plese pass the full XPath to update my answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It helped me to solve my problem.